# Find and Replace REGEX results with new string

Tags: regex, replace, find

I want to replace a 10 digits pictureID number to a single text string in my WP-database (`wp_post field: post_content`)

`pictureid=0001234567` (where the last 7 digits are different for every photo)

to a single value:

```
sourceids=2518
```

When I query for the pictureID numbers wit REGEX it seems te return al the records I want to change.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP 'pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Next: what to do to change pictureID in those records found to the `sourceids=2518`

**I did try**

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, 'REGEXP 'pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'','sourceids=2518');
```

but this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE(pictureid,'000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',sourceid)`

Comment: Hi Hamnshu, could you explain why this would solve OP's issue please?

Comment: actually this function replaces picture id with the sourceid where pattern is as given 000..did you try with this ?

Comment: Its not working,I did the following:  testing REGEXP:

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP 'pictureid=0001119708'  = WORKING    


SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP 'pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'   =  WORKING
       
Trying to replace 'pictureid=000#######'  (where # is any numeric value, example: 00012345670 by this single value 'sourceids-2518'
      

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP_REPLACE ('pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]','sourceids=2518')  = NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the reply is poorly formatted so will do it this way

Its not working,I did the following:  testing REGEXP:

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP 'pictureid=0001119708'  = WORKING

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP 'pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'   =  WORKING

Trying to replace 'pictureid=000#######'  (where # is any numeric value, example: 00012345670 by this single value 'sourceids-2518'

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` REGEXP_REPLACE ('pictureid=000[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]','sourceids=2518')  = NOT WORKING